# How can I do form validation to unknown form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

Now I am currently working on a task which I need to do a form validation by JQuery validator on a client side using java script.The main idea is we do not hard code the field names such as name age country I need to validate the form in more general way.We have used Javascript framework handlebar.js to create a web page for input this data is derived from registry as rxt registry extension file.I am very new to handlebar framework and I have tried out simple sample to handlebar.But It is not workin for me.I have shared my html and js code below .Please can anyone give some suggestions to correct this error.Thanks in advance?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>   
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Handlebars.js Example Template</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="menu-placeholder"></div>
  <script id="menu-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <ul>
   <li><a href="{{linkURL1}}">{{linkName1}}</a></li>
   <li><a href="{{linkURL2}}">{{linkName2}}</a></li>
   <li><a href="{{linkURL3}}">{{linkName3}}</a></li>
   <li><a href="{{linkURL4}}">{{linkName4}}</a></li>
   <li><a href="{{linkURL5}}">{{linkName5}}</a></li>
      </ul>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js" /></script>
 
    </body>
</html>
```

and my javascript code below

```html
var menuData = {
    linkName1 : "Link 1",
    linkName2 : "Link 2",
    linkName3 : "Link 3",
    linkName4 : "Link 4",
    linkName5 : "Link 5",
    linkURL1 : "http://google.com",
    linkURL2 : "http://jaskokoyn.com",
    linkURL3 : "http://yahoo.com",
    linkURL4 : "http://youtube.com",
    linkURL5 : "http://twitter.com"
};


// Grab the HTML source that needs to be compiled
var menuSource = document.getElementById( 'menu-template' ).innerHTML;
// Compiles the source
var menuTemplate = Handlebars.compile( menuSource );



// Process Template with Data
document.getElementById( 'menu-placeholder' ).innerHTML = menuTemplate( menuData );
```

Comment: Also, please review the ["How to Ask?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: have edited my question. I ll review How to ask page :-)

Answer (score 0):

use required attribute to the field name, for eg

```
<input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
```

and in javascript write only:

```
$("#yourform").validate();
```

this way it validates input as email. you do not need to hardcode field name, rules in javascript, but in html element

**Method 2:**
And if you want to add required rules to all inputs with class name req

```
<input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" class="req">

$("input.req").each (function (){
    $(this).rules( "add", {
      required: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: Can we use type of a input and validate the specific form.Because I need a general way that I can validate any form that my js met.

Comment: Can I use the type attribute for specifically define rule? if the type text some rules or if the type url define somerule like this?

Comment: Yes, in the place of $('input.req') use $('nput[type="text"] it will add rules to all text fields

Comment: If I need both class and type can I add like this $( "input.req" && 'input[type]="text'' ' ).rules( "add", {
  required: true,
});

Comment: use $('input.req input[type="text"]')

Comment: Simply use `class="required"` in place of `class="req"` and then you would not need the `.rules()` method at all.